# Why pushstate triggered popstate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, history.js

I'm using history.js

```
 https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/
```

HTML5 History/State APIs. As the document example `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onpopstate` when calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a clicking on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript). And the event is only triggered when the user navigates between two history entries for the same document.

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        window.location.href // reload page
    });

    // Change our States
    History.pushState({state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.pushState({state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"); // logs {state:2}, "State 2", "?state=2"
    History.replaceState({state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.pushState(null, null, "?state=4"); // logs {}, '', "?state=4"
    History.back(); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"
    History.back(); // logs {state:1}, "State 1", "?state=1"
    History.back(); // logs {}, "Home Page", "?"
    History.go(2); // logs {state:3}, "State 3", "?state=3"

})(window);
```

But when I add history.js and when I calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState(), it trigger a popstate/statechange event every time. and ajax not working properly and pages are double reloaded. I have found some discussion [https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/312 / https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/issues/96] on it but no solution has found.